# Why is my Virtual Host not found?

Tags: apache, virtual, host

I'm using xamp as my desktop test server.  I have other apps which work fine.

This URL works:  http://localhost/PatchUpdate/
I'm trying to get this url to work : PatchUpdate.local

My httpd-vhost.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName PatchUpdate.local
    DocumentRoot "D:/app/xampp/htdocs/PatchUpdate"
    ErrorLog "logs/PatchUpdate.log"
    CustomLog "logs/PatchUpdate.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The odd thing is that I have other hosts which work perfectly.  Here's one which uses jkmount to map my client and server side

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/app/xampp/htdocs/OutageReport"
    ServerName OutageReport.local
    JkMount  /OutageReportSvc/* worker1
    ErrorLog "logs/OutageReport.log"
    CustomLog "logs/OutageReport.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Checking httpd -S gives me this:

```
port 80 namevhost PatchUpdate.local (D:/app/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:105)
```

So that looks like it's set up properly and Apache sees the mapping. But when I try to hit 
    patchupdate.local

I get a "Server Not Found" error and the url is replaced with 
    http://www.patchupdate.local/

Does anyone have any idea why this particular virtual host doesn't work when other hosts do?

Thank you

Comment: ServerName is patchupdate.local, not www.patchupdate.local

Comment: Found it. I also had to add 127.0.0.1    PatchUpdate.local  to my etc/host file.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I also had to add 127.0.0.1 PatchUpdate.local to my etc/host file